# Webpack - Bundle file seems to contain itself?

Tags: angular, webpack

First - I'm totally new to webpack and have inherited an application that is very slow to load. First thing I noticed is that the bundle.js file is almost 13mb.

I installed the webpack bundle analyzer which showed the following:

[image: Bundle Analyzer Results]

If I hover over the main.***.bundle.js it says it is about 5.13mb. Can anyone help with what this is showing? It seems to suggest that it contains itself (that is the name of my bundle file as shown below).

[image]

Comment: You should not be building source maps into production, you should be using node_env true env variable, and you should be using uglify to compress. 13mb implies you're in a development mode bundle

Comment: Thanks @AndyRay, would that be why the bundle file seems to be contained in itself?

Comment: _It seems to suggest that it contains itself_ - what do you mean by contains itself? can you update the picture with arrows?

Comment: The top part of the image shows the same name as the bundle itself and is 5mb in size. Is that normal?